# Get notification when added / updated any single contact in phone book in android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I want to sync contact whenever new contact added or updated. don't want to sync any specific time.

Comment: Please provide more information. This question is too generic to provide any answer. What have you tried so far? What error you see? What code do you have? Read how to ask questions in Help section.

Answer (score 0):

You can add ContentObserver with service this will notify you on contact data changes. Just register contact uri with ContentObserver
Ref -https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/ContentObserver.html

Example -http://www.adityathakker.com/android-content-observer-react-on-content-change/